# Shell if[[]] giving syntax error while executing

Tags: linux, shell

I have a shell script which uses `if` to check some conditions. But because of some reason the `if` statement is giving me a syntax error.

```
./Sample.sh: line 82: conditional binary operator expected
./Sample.sh: line 82: syntax error near `${myId}'
./Sample.sh: line 82: `if [[ -v ${myId} ]]'
```

and my shell script is like

```
myId=${id}_CONTEXT
echo \* ${myId}
if [[ -v ${myId} ]]
then
    
    echo \* true
else
    echo \* false
    envVarSuccess=false
fi
```

What could be the reason for the same.?

Linux version is `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)`.

Shell version is

```
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

How should I rewrite my shell?

Comment: Which shell are you running this with (and which specific version of that shell)? `[[` is a ksh and bash syntax; `sh` doesn't support it.

Comment: Also, `-v` is even less portable than `[[`. Even on bash, I'd suggest `[[ ${!myId} ]]` instead unless you know for sure that the specific version in use supports the construct.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The same sh is running in another servers without error. Shell version updated.

Comment: `sh` doesn't guarantee you it'll support _anything_ that isn't in the POSIX sh specification, and `[[` is not part of that specification. So when you run `sh somescript`, that script is only guaranteed to work if it only uses POSIX syntax, and no bash syntax, ksh syntax, zsh syntax, etc. It _might_ work if it uses other syntax, depending on which shell provides `sh` on your system and which subset of features it disables in compatibility mode, but there are no guarantees.

Comment: Note that `bash --version` does not tell you what the active shell is; it tells you what _the first copy of `bash` in the `PATH` is_, which can be something different. If you want to know which version of bash is in use (if it is in fact bash), run `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` _inside your script_.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your bash version is too old. In a terminal try

```
help test
```

with my

```
bash -version
```

> GNU bash, version 5.1.0(1)-rc2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

I get:

> ```
>   ...
>
>   Other operators:
>     
>       -o OPTION      True if the shell option OPTION is enabled.
>       -v VAR         True if the shell variable VAR is set.
>       -R VAR         True if the shell variable VAR is set and is a name
>                      reference.
>
>   ...
> ```

-> Did you see the "-v VAR" in your case?

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212192/249463 this feature is only available for bash v4.2 and above (yours is v4.1).

Also note that the right syntax is

```
 if [ -v myId ] ...
```

and not

```
 if [ -v ${myId} ] ...
```

Also according to the cited link, this

```
 if [ -n "${myId}" ] ...
```

is maybe a viable Bourne-like shells alternative.

Hoping that at least one of these two suggestions will work for you.

Comment: `/bin/test` (and its alias `/bin/[`) doesn't ever support `-v`. It can't, because only the shell itself (and not external commands that shell invokes) can see non-exported variables. Granted, `test` and `[` are often provided by builtins, but using functionality that disappears whenever a command is used in a non-builtin context is fragile, and there's no reason to do it instead of using the explicitly extended-shell-syntax-only `[[` construct instead.